# C#.net 2010 desktop where app on same computer and used by more than one person

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, vb.net-2010

In an existing C#.net 2010 desktop application, I would need to have 2 users share the same computer. Both users will run the same desktop application but have access to different files and folders on the network share. Each person will have their own unqiue config file to show what files they have access to.

Based upon what I have said, I have the following questions to ask:

1. Will I need separate installs of the application on the same computer? Part of the install process includes placing the app.config file in the correct location. If so, can you tell me what I need to do for the separate installs?
2. If I do not need separate installs, what should I do about the separate app.config files? Each person's config file will point to files they directly have access to. I do not want each person to access the other person's config file.

Comment: *Settings* is designed to hold per-user information. *app.config* isn't.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean and show me some code I can use as an example to know what you are referring to?

Comment: [Using Settings in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) dates back to C# 2 but is still valid.